# setTimeout and display none with a fader timer- How to do it chronologically?

Tags: javascript, css, settimeout, hidden

I am sitting with a project in need of an overlay which fades out when hovered upon and goes to display: none (not visibility: hidden, it does need to be display: none).

The setup is a big confusing, but I will try to explain it:

The overlay comes up when I hover a menu point under my mega menu. When I move the cursor to the overlay it should naturally dissapear and the menu close.

This works very well with this code:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("overlayed");

function mouseOver() {

  element.classList.add("mystyle");


  setTimeout(function() {
    element.classList.remove("mystyle");
  }, 500);

}
```

```css
push {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.overlayerstwo {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 30%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #111;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}

.mystyle {
  display: none;
  animation-name: fadeOut;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: .5
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.mystyler {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Here is something. Overlay comes back when hovering me!</h1>
<div class="overlayerstwo" id="overlayed" onmouseover="mouseOver()"></div>
<div class="push">
  <p>Here is an item being overlayed</p>
</div>
```

With this setup the overlay dissapears right away. I am trying to merge it with the fadeOut keyframe animation before it goes black. I have tried different tactics, like adding a second timeout event but all it does is loop through and end up showing the overlay permanently after.

So the order I want to achieve is as follows:

- Add a class that fires the keyframe animation fadeOut for .5 sec
- Remove keyframe animation class
- Add display: block class
- Remove display: block class (essentially resetting it, so you can get the overlay up again by hovering its triggerpoint)

So my question is, how do I get all of these to fire every time I hover over the overlay?
One of the things I tried was this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("overlayed");
  element.classList.add("mystyle");
  
setTimeout(function(){
 var element = document.getElementById("overlayed");
  element.classList.remove("mystyle");
}, 500);

setTimeout(function(){
 var element = document.getElementById("overlayed");
  element.classList.add("mystyletwo");
}, 500);

setTimeout(function(){
 var element = document.getElementById("overlayed");
  element.classList.remove("mystyletwo");
}, 510);
```

With the css

```
.mystyle{  
    animation-name: fadeOut;
    animation-duration: .5s;
}

.mystyletwo{
    display: block;
}
```

Which did not work. I hope someone can help me figure out how to get it to work!

Comment: You shouldn't do this with a timeout, you should register an event for when the animation has ended. You can remove display:block in your event listener function being confident the animation has finished. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event

Comment: Hmm, I'm not entirely sure how that would look in practice!

Answer (score -1):

> if the timeline will be like this: 
> **visible -> hover -> animation -> opacity to 0 -> display: none**

**using CSS with JS logic:**

```js
element.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    element.style.opacity = "0";
    element.style.transition = "all 0.3s";

    // when finish the animation then call display none 
    setTimeout(function() {
        element.style.display = "none";
    }, 300); // put the same number (milliseconds) of  duration of transition (or more, not less)
});
```

using this method you don't need to complex your code...

the trick really is because we use `element.style`

that is only put the CSS, but technically...

if there is a transition Javascript don't know it,

so it will run the `setTimeout()` directly after adding styles,

so now CSS will do the animation but javascript will quietly continue the code (which in our case, says that after 300 seconds add display: none;)

Comment: Hmm, it does not seem to work for me - when the event has fired once the overlay gets display: none, and not reset. So it cannot re-fire whenever it has completed!